# How to log parameters of slow queries?

Tags: postgresql

How do I log the parameter values ($1, $2, ...) in the slow query log?

I am enabling slow query log with this statement:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 5000
```

However it doesn't log the parameter values. Even if I attempt to change the variable:

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

it doesn't work because it starts logging all the queries, but what I want is to log slow queries with parameters that cause the slowness.

Comment: log_min_duration_statement works for me.

`LOG:  duration: 1.435 ms  execute P0_5: UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + $1 WHERE aid = $2;`
`DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '-1565', $2 = '1688512'`

Comment: @jjanes for me it doesn't, it shows all the queries , slow and fast and without duration

Comment: What is your version?  What is your setting of log_error_verbosity?

Comment: @jjanes I am using v 10.12 , `log_error_verbosity` is not configured, I suppose 'default' is set

Comment: @jjanes I was able to show parameters after setting `log_error_verbosity` to `DETAIL` and the parameters are shown on the next line now

Comment: `detail` is not a valid value for that parameter. Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL and not some fork of it?